# What anime is this doll from?

Tags: merchandise

Does anyone know what anime this doll is from?

[image: Anime doll]

[Here is the tag on the doll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iee13.png).

Answer (score 7):

From the [tag alone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iee13.png), we can tell this UFO Catcher prize is part of a set from [*Kaitou Saint Tail*](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1567/Kaitou_Saint_Tail). The character is [Ruby](http://sainttail.wikia.com/wiki/Ruby), Meimi's brown pet hedgehog.